# TinyMCE React add custom component to toolbar

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

When creating a TinyMCE editor in React, it is possible to add a custom button to the toolbar using the following code:

```
<Editor
...
init={{
    ...
    setup: (editor) => {
        editor.ui.registry.addButton('test' {
            text: 'Test',
            onAction: () => console.log('Test')
        });
    }
}}
/>
```

Besides `addButton`, there are other options such as `addIcon`, `addMenuItem`, and `addSidebar`. However, I can't figure out how to include my own custom component.

Say I wanted to add a very simple div/component

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

or

```
<TestComponent />
```

to the end of the toolbar, how would I do this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the **Editor.ui.registry.addButton** method.

Try like below example

```
import React from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

const MyCustomButton = ({ editor }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    editor.insertContent('Hello World!');
  };

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      My Button
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const handleEditorChange = (content, editor) => {
    console.log(content);
  };

  return (
    <Editor
      apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
      onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
      init={{
        height: 500,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: ['lists', 'code'],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | myCustomButton',
        setup: editor => {
          editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomButton', {
            text: 'My Button',
            onAction: () => {
              editor.insertContent('Hello World!');
            }
          });
        }
      }}
      render={({ editor, ...rest }) => (
        <>
          <MyCustomButton editor={editor} />
          <Editor {...rest} />
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

**MyCustomButton** component before the **Editor** component so that it appears in the toolbar. When the button is clicked, it will insert the text "Hello World!" into the editor.

Comment: What version of `@tinymce/tinymce-react` are you using? There is no such prop `render` in @latest.

Comment: @DJSpud The render prop is not needed. You can remove it from the <Editor> component and update your code as follows

Answer (score 0):

[official website](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/)

[official Github](https://github.com/tinymce)

You can try to search in website or Github by keywords to explore more examples or tests.

Here are what you needed.

## addButton

1. registry by **registry.addButton**, code your feature in onAction, such as insertContent.
2. add the name which you registry in toolbar, split by space, for example:

```
toolbar: 'undo redo addTestList'
```

```
init={{
  toolbar: 'addTestList',
  setup: function (editor) {

    editor.ui.registry.addButton('addTestList', {
      text: 'addTestList',
      onAction: function (_) {
        editor.insertContent(`<div>
        <ul>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>`);
      }
    });
  },
}}
```

## addIcon

1. registry your custom icon.
2. use **icon:"your-custom-icon"** in other api config, for example addButton.

```
init={{
  toolbar: 'addTestList undo',
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addIcon('addTestListIcon', '<svg height="24" width="24"><path d="M12 0 L24 24 L0 24 Z" /></svg>');

    editor.ui.registry.addButton('addTestList', {
        icon: "addTestListIcon",
        onAction: function (_) {
          editor.insertContent(`<div>
              <ul>
                  <li>Test 1</li>
                  <li>Test 2</li>
              </ul>
          </div>`);
        }
    });
  },
 }}
```

## addMenuItem

1. registry menu item in setup.
2. set menu to custom
3. use custom menu in menubar

```
init={{
  menu: {
    custom: {
      title: "Custom",
      items: "myCustomMenuItem"
    }
  },
  menubar: "custom",
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem("myCustomMenuItem", {
      text: "My Custom Menu Item",
      onAction: function () {
        editor.insertContent('<input type="checkbox">Hello</input>');
      }
    });
  },
 }}
```

## addSidebar

```
init={{
  toolbar: 'mysidebar undo',
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addSidebar('mysidebar', {
      tooltip: 'My sidebar',
      icon: 'comment',
      onShow: (api) => {
        api.element().innerHTML = 'Hello world!';
      },
    });
  },
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple example on how to add your own custom components such as `addIcon`, `addMenuItem`, and `addSidebar`.

You may find more information on customization under the docs link [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/creating-custom-menu-items/).

Do note most of the examples are under `How-to guides -> Creating custom UI` components.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#toolbar-button',
  toolbar: 'myOwnComponent mysidebar',
  menu: {
    custom: { title: 'Custom Menu', items: 'undo redo myCustomMenuItem' }
  },
  menubar: 'undo redo custom',
  setup: (editor) => {
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('myOwnComponent', {
      text: 'This is my component',
      tooltip: 'Hover to see me',
      icon: 'triangleUp',
      onAction: (_) => editor.insertContent(`
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Test 1</li>
          <li>Test 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>`)
    }), 
    editor.ui.registry.addIcon('triangleUp', '<svg height="24" width="24"><path d="M12 0 L24 24 L0 24 Z" /></svg>'),
    editor.ui.registry.addSidebar('mysidebar', {
      tooltip: 'My sidebar',
      icon: 'comment',
      onShow: (api) => {
        api.element().innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Test 1</li>
          <li>Test 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>`;
      },
    }),
    editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem('myCustomMenuItem', {
      text: 'My Custom Menu Item',
      onAction: () => alert('Menu item clicked')
    })
  }
})
```

I have also included an example **[codepen](https://codepen.io/cloudre01/pen/GRXZNvY?editors=0010)** for your reference.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the key `test` to the `toolbar` property in your `init` object

```
<Editor
    init={{
        toolbar: "test",
        setup: (editor) => {
            editor.ui.registry.addButton('test' {
                text: 'Test',
                onAction: () => console.log('Test')
            });
        }
    }}
/>
```